# Как правильно писать Подразделение управления персонала (или "персоналом")?

Tags: морфология

Как правильно писать Подразделение управления персонала (или "персоналом")?
Мы же не говорим "Подразделение управления логистикой, маркетингом"

Comment: Все же не понятно. В случае словосочетания "Управление Федеральной налоговой службы" используется Р.П.,а "Управление персоналом" - точно такое же название адм.органа - Т.П.   ?????

Comment: Существует Федеральная налоговая служба, то есть орган исполнительной власти. В состав ФНС входит структурная единица, которую называют "Управление" - это часть ФНС, отсюда и Р.п. В нашем примере мы имеем "Подразделение (для осуществления) управления персоналом". Здесь возможен только один вариант  с Т.п. - "управление персоналом", так как "управление персонала" читается как управление, составляющее часть персонала.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: подразделение управления персоналом.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

А. Когда используется Т.п.

Можно управлять государством, предприятием, автомобилем, и это будет управление государством, предприятием, автомобилем (Т.п.).

Б. Когда используется Р.п.

Но у слова "управление" есть и другое значение - орган управления, например: Управление железной дороги (административный орган), рулевое управление автомобиля - совокупность приборов и технических средств (Р.п.). Здесь "управление" определяется как часть структурной системы, поэтому и применяется Р.п.

В. Решение

В приведенном примере административный орган уже называется "подразделением", а управление персоналом (Т.п.) - это его функция.

ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНОЕ ПОЯСНЕНИЕ
а) И логистика, и маркетинг – это уже УПРАВЛЕНИЕ  потоками товаров и услуг, поэтому нельзя управлять управлением.

б) Общее значение Т.п. – это обозначение предмета, с помощью которого осуществляется действие: управлять персоналом - управление персоналом.

Общее значение Р.п.   – партитивное, обозначающее часть или принадлежность, отнесенность.  Сравнить: обучать персонал  (В.п.) – обучение  персонала (Р.п.), также читать книгу – чтение книги.